# Filtrar resultados MYSQL de acordo com o resultado de uma linha

Tags: mysql

Estou tendo um problema para realizar um filtro especifico em uma consulta no MySQL.

Estou construindo um sistema de pesquisa onde tenho as seguintes tabelas:

- **Questionários**: com o nome do questionarios
- **Perguntas**: contendo as perguntas do questionário, com `foreign key` apontando para a tabela questionário
- **Respostas**: contendo as respostas de cada pergunta, com o `foreign key` apontando para perguntas
- **Fichas**: Informações sobre quem respondeu
- **Respostas Dadas**: Contém as respostas dadas por cada pessoa.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
[Tabela Fichas]
- ID
- created_at
- latitude
- longitude

[Tabela Respostas dadas]
- id
- ficha_id
- resposta_id
- pergunta_id
```

Eu preciso de uma consulta que me retorne a quantidade de `respostas_id` de acordo com uma pergunta especifica.

Por exemplo, preciso saber dos que responderam "23" no campo `resposta_id` quando `pergunta_id = "81"`, respondeu nas outras perguntas.

Já estou batendo cabeça a dias nisso mas não estou conseguindo. Pensei até em criar uma view que me organizasse os dados de forma que cada pergunta fosse uma coluna e as respostas fossem as linhas, mas também não consegui.

Comment: `select count(*) from respostas_dadas where resposta_id = id_da_resposta_a_contar`, experimenta isto.

Comment: Se entendi certo você quer saber as outras respostas de quem selecionou a resposta 23 da pergunta 81, é isso? Outra dúvida, quando o usuário responde o questionário inteiro, só é gravado um registro de `ficha` para ele?

Comment: Você quer obter uma determinada resposta de uma pergunta? É isso?

Comment: Opa, obrigado. É isso mesmo. E quando a pessoa responde o questionário inteiro, é salvo um registro na tabela **fichas** e as respostas são salvas na tabela **respostas_dadas**.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Tabela Respostas dadas]
- id
- ficha_id
- resposta_id
- pergunta_id
```

> Por exemplo, preciso saber dos que responderam "23" no campo
>   resposta_id quando pergunta_id = "81", respondeu nas outras perguntas.

**responderam "23" no campo resposta_id quando pergunta_id = "81"**

```
select id
from respostas
where pergunta_id = "81"
and resposta_id = "23"
```

**respondeu nas outras perguntas.**

```
select *
from respostas
where pergunta_id <> "81"
and id in (select id
           from respostas
           where pergunta_id = "81"
           and resposta_id = "23")
```

Creio ser isto. []s

Comment: Fera, muito, muito obrigado. Seu raciocinio me ajudou e solucionar, ficou **select respostas.valor, count(*) from respostas_dadas join respostas on respostas.id = respostas_dadas.resposta_id
where respostas_dadas.pergunta_id <> "26"
and ficha_id in (select ficha_id
           from respostas_dadas
           where pergunta_id = "26"
           and resposta_id = "82") group by respostas_dadas.resposta_id**, agora é trabalhar no PHP para tornar essa consulta genérica. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos que postaram.
Com a ajuda do Motta cheguei na seguinte consulta:

```
 select respostas.valor, count(*) from respostas_dadas join respostas on
   respostas.id = respostas_dadas.resposta_id
   where respostas_dadas.pergunta_id <> "26"
    and ficha_id in
        (select ficha_id from respostas_dadas
        where pergunta_id = "26"
        and resposta_id = "82") group by respostas_dadas.resposta_id
```

Esse é um sisteminha de estudo que estou fazendo, pensando em uma empresa de pesquisas que tem que montar vários questionários. Na tabela **questionarios** eu jogo os dados gerais de cada questionário, na tabela **perguntas** eu jogo as perguntas desse questionário, na tabela **respostas** eu jogo as respostas de cada pergunta, na tabela **fichas** eu salvo os dados gerais de cada ficha, quando foi feito, local, e por último as respostas de cada ficha eu jogo na tabela **respostas_dadas**. 
Esse filtro que estou tentando fazer é para perguntas tipo

> *"Das pessoas com sexo masculino ( pergunta 26, resposta 23 ) quantos vão votar no prefeito X"*?

Valeu gente.
E desculpem não conseguir formatar o código, primeira vez que estou postando aqui. Segui a orientação de dar os 4 espaços mas o trecho da consulta não está saindo formatado.